# Getting frame or bounds of UIView within UIViewRepresentable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my `ContentView` I have a simple custom view:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Hi")
        Circles().frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        Text("Bye")
    }
}
```

where `Circles` is a `UIViewRepresentable`:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CircleView  {
    return CircleView()
}
```

`CircleView` is A `UIView` but I'm unable to find get frame or bounds where the height and width are non-zero. The view displays at the correct size, but I can't where in the UIView life cycle that layout has completed. (At `init` time the height/width are still 0)

Answer (score 1):

At least in `UIView.layoutSubviews` the bounds is already valid (I used override it for the needs of layouting sublayers).

```
open func layoutSubviews()
```

You can override other `UIView` methods to find out where it becomes defined for your needs.